# Access attributes of a deleted IFeature in ArcObjects 10.1

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.1, extensions

I am migrating code for an ArcGIS extension from 9.3 to 10.1.
The code is throwing an exception in one place.

My duty is just to migrate it to 10.1, so I really don't like to do any modification more than few lines of code.

The code is searching for a feature that was deleted by the user on a child version, 
but 
1 - it is not posted yet to the default version 
2 - The edit session is still open and not saved.

so before the save it is trying to validate some business rules.

```
IFeatureWorkspace childWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)childVersion;
IFeatureClass childOperationalUnit = childWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass("OperationUnit");
IFeature childFeature = childOperationalUnit.GetFeature(Id_Of_Deleted_Feature);
if (childFeature != null)
{
 string operationName = childFeature.get_value(Index_Of_Name_Column); 

if (operationName == "somevalue")
......
}
```

So, the code is trying to access the attributes of a deleted feature.
The code was working on 9.3

But on 10.1 is not working and giving me the error:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004100C): The feature is deleted
The error happening on the line where we try to get the attributes of the feature with get_value

so, 10.1 can find the feature but cannot access its attributes.

is there any easy way to keep the code working without really modifying lots of code?

Comment: Did you try [IDataChangesEx](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/00444a07-bd81-4947-ac9f-5fc4888f13dc.htm)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Kirk
That worked.
IDataChangesEx has a method called ExtractEx , which return a cursor with the modified rows, and you can actually access the attributes for a deleted row.